# Persian text separated in dompdf

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, dompdf, persian

I used DomPdf to create pdf with persian characters , but pdf text is separated like `ت اری خ س ف ارش :` in the event that should be `تاریخ سفارش :`

Code is :

```
    $logo = storage_path('logo/logo.jpg');
    $font = storage_path('fonts/IRRoya.ttf');
    $barcode = DNS2D::getBarcodePNG($order["registration_number"], "QRCODE",5,5);
    $date = jDateTime::strftime('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($order['order_date']));
    $f_date = jDateTime::convertNumbers($date);
    $date_text = 'تاریخ سفارش :';
    $reverse = $this->utf8_strrev($date_text);
    PDF::setOptions(['defaultFont' => 'IRRoya']);
    return PDF::loadView('bill.bill',compact('order','logo','font','barcode','f_date','reverse'))->setPaper('a4')->setWarnings(false)->download();
```

How i can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `fagd` function in `php-gd-persion` project.

Here is the source code

https://github.com/slashmili/php-gd-persian/blob/master/phpgd/fagd.php

In your code you should replace `$date_text = 'تاریخ سفارش :';` with this:

```
$date_text = fagd('تاریخ سفارش :');
```